# Join same two tables multiple times in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have problem with my query and i can not figure it how to do it.
What i want to do is to display "Ban By" name to table. I know how to join two tables and that is what i did here:

```
SELECT reason, expired, created, actor_id, name 
FROM bm_player_ban_records 
LEFT JOIN bm_players ON bm_player_ban_records.player_id = bm_players.id 
WHERE bm_players.name = 'NexoR'
```

but i need to join the same tables again and now i need to pair them by actor_id to id and than display name and this is where my brain stopped and do not know how to do it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqmvb.jpg <- images

Comment: Can you create a [mre] using [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) ?

Comment: Include sample data and desired output in question as text tables, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  
    reason, 
    expired, 
    created, 
    actor_id, 
    name 

FROM 
    bm_player_ban_records
  LEFT JOIN 
    bm_players AS BAN_by ON Ban_by.id = bm_player_ban_records.player_id 
  LEFT JOIN
    bm_players AS ACTORE ON ACTORE.id = bm_player_ban_records.actor_id
WHERE 
    Ban_by.name = 'NexoR'
```

you will likely need to prefix the fields in the SELECT with the correct alias for the table